# Monero Fork: Transaction hash is not generated from the wallet RPC

Tags: monerod, transaction-confirmation, monero-forks

I have forked monero and created a separate chain. When I transfer money using the wallet RPC, money gets transferred and the remaining amount is updated in the balance. Then, the transaction hash is not created. After checking with an explorer, I can see it's in the mempool. Blocks are not created for more than 22 hrs but network hashrate is 2 Mhs.

Any solutions, Please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe the daemon had issues during the port process, try to rebase and start it from fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout is 7 days but if the transaction doesn't find its way in a block within a day, it could be dropped.

> Why the transaction can't get in a block is another matter, but typically this can be due to a double spend, fee too low, or violating the minimum mixin rules, among others.

You can check more details about this, reading the [What causes transactions to exit the Memory Pool?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/58/what-causes-transactions-to-exit-the-memory-pool/72#72) answer.

Comment: That's not answering the question. The OP has stated the tx is in the mempool and is not asking anything related to tx time-out.

Answer (score 2):

If the tx is in the mempool, a tx hash must exist. If the wallet RPC is not returning to you the tx hash in the result of the [transfer](https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#transfer) call, your fork codebase has issues. Blocks not being mined *could* be related, but could equally be an issue with your miners or pool implementation (which obviously also need to be updated inline with your fork code changes).